# Serve static files with golang

Tags: go, server, static-libraries, gorilla

I'm trying to develop a simple web application but I'mhaving problem with serving my static files.

The file structure is:

- main

--main.go

-serve

--listenAndServe.go

--templates

---login.html

---assets

----css

----fonts

----js

my code is this:

```
    import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "time"

        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    )

    var (
        router = mux.NewRouter()
    )

    func (c *Conn) ListenAndServe() {
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./templates/assets"))
        http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fs))
        router.HandleFunc("/", c.IndexPageHandler)
        router.HandleFunc("/login.html", c.LoginPageHandler)
        log.Println("Listening...")
        http.Handle("/", router)
        muxWithMiddlewares := http.TimeoutHandler(router, time.Minute*30, 
        "Timeout!")
         http.ListenAndServe(":8080", muxWithMiddlewares)
      }
```

But for some reason when I run it from main.go it serves the html but not the assets. I would really apreciate some tips. Thanks!

Comment: What (status) does the server respond with for your assets?

Comment: `http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fs))` and `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", muxWithMiddlewares)` are incompatible. The first one says "have the **default** ServeMux handle assets", the second says "start the server using the **non-default** muxWithMiddlewares handler". Use either the default mux, or the gorilla mux, but not both.

Comment: It doesn't actually responde with any errors. It just does not serve them. The HTML is served just fine

Comment: Thanks for clarify that @mkopriva! I'm trying to fix that

Comment: Try to remove the last slash for `StripPrefix` so that you have  `http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets", fs))` (or whatever you have after fixing the thing @mkopriva mentioned). I think i've had similar issues with `FileServer` not liking not having the leading slash

Comment: Please follow instructions in this post: https://medium.com/@hau12a1/golang-http-serve-static-files-correctly-5feb98ae9da1

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fileServer))
```

Note that static, in your case assets only has a single forward slash within the stripPreFix function.

Hope this helps.